# What does Mother Late Spinster mean on Baptism?

Tags: baptism-records

Looking at a Baptism transcript I came across this:

> Mother Late Spinster

Does it mean she is married or that her husband has died (which would be a worry as she has had 8 children since then!)

Comment: It didn't include as in quotes....  It said Mother Late Spinster

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Where and when was this written?  Was the name of the child and/or the mother likely to be a non-unique name in that area at that time?  A reference/link to and an image of that entry would be useful to see.

Comment: What is the location and date for this baptism?  Can you see any other entries in the register that have a notation like this?

Answer (score 2):

The word `late` can just mean "previously" as in [Wiktionary's sense 7](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/late#English) of the word:

> Existing or holding some position not long ago, but not now; departed,
>   or gone out of office.

It is sometimes seen on a certificate where somebody (usually a women) has had multiple names, for example "Jane Smith late Jones formerly Wheeler" so I would guess that is the meaning we are dealing with here.

That said "late Spinster" would appear to be a statement of the obvious in that all married women were once spinsters... Is it perhaps trying to say that the child being baptised was born before the marriage?

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret that as telling me that the Mother had died (was Late) and was unmarried before she died. But that doesn't fit if she subsequently has 8 children -- are you sure that this is a child of the same mother?

Another possibility is that the child was conceived or even born while the mother was still a Spinster -- how close is the baptism to the marriage?

Comment: That's what I thought but the father is on Baptism record and there is also a record of their marriage.  Thanks for quick reply

Comment: I will keep digging and double check....  As always you find something and then cant find it again - smh